# pairwise comparison with nlme

Tags: r, mixed-models

I am running a mixed effect model with nlme package in R. My data include 82 animals (with repetition), these 82 animals are grouped by 3 breeds (defined as categorical variable), my continuous variable is time time-squared, response is MY.
The form of mixed model is:

```
model<-lme(MY~time + breed*time + time-squared,random=1|Animal, data=mydata)
```

The results obtained as follows:

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: na.omit(centred_phuong) 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  93698.27 93769.46 -46840.13
Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | Cow_code
        (Intercept) Residual
StdDev:    1.283306 2.453689
Fixed effects: MY ~ time + time * Breed + time_squared 
                         Value Std.Error    DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept)          1.3398578 0.2495665 20048   5.36874  0.0000
DFC                  0.0523516 0.0003675 20048 142.43468  0.0000
Breed2               0.4998856 0.3521235    78   1.41963  0.1597
Breed3              -0.3683371 0.3520760    78  -1.04619  0.2987
Time_squared         0.0001213 0.0000025 20048  48.14845  0.0000
Time:Breed2          0.0084160 0.0005011 20048  16.79463  0.0000
Time:Breed3         -0.0086297 0.0005028 20048 -17.16272  0.0000
```

As I understood from these results, the model compares intercepts and slopes of breed 2 and 3 with that of breed 1., and there is no comparison between breed 2 and breed 2? IS there anyway to specify this?

I hope to get you advices! Thanks

Comment: First of all, since you are dealing with time series, you need to check if there is autocorrelation of residuals. If there is, you need to specify an appropriate correlation structure. Furthermore, I might test if including the breed in the random effect could improve the model. For pair-wise comparisons you can try function `glht` in package multcomp.

Comment: Hi Roland, I fact I tried already glht function, but these results are different from nlme results:
Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


Fit: lme.formula(fixed = Red_MY ~ Centred_DFC + Centred_DFC * Breed + 
    Squared_Centred_DFC, data = Red_MY_parity1, random = ~Centred_DFC | 
    Cow_code, na.action = na.omit)

Linear Hypotheses:
           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
2 - 1 == 0   0.5762     0.4100   1.405   0.3380  
3 - 1 == 0  -0.2701     0.4099  -0.659   0.7873  
3 - 2 == 0  -0.8463     0.4099  -2.065   0.0973

Comment: Agree with @Roland. To do the pairwise comparisons make your dependent variable a single factor using `interaction(df$Breed, df$Time) and pass that to 'glht'.

Comment: Hi "thijs van den bergh": do you mean creating a new variable as" mydata$newvar<-interaction(mydata$Breed,mydata$time),
and then include it both in lme and glht?

Comment: I created a new variable as "interaction between time and breed" and replace Breed*time in the original model by "newvar" and run lme again but got this warning: Error in MEEM(object, conLin, control$niterEM) : 
  'Calloc' could not allocate memory (20719944 of 8 bytes)